# Symbol for kernel of restriction map in Galois cohomology

Tags: symbols

I don't know how to typeset first symbol in the following line

[image]

I thought it could be some variation on \coprod or \amalgam, but I could not find it.

Comment: If you have the PDF you can check exactly what  font and character that is, but it looks like a cyrillic Sh to me rather than a character from a math font (but I can't read Cyrillic so I could be mistaken:-)

Comment: I guess it is as https://wstein.org/edu/2010/582e/refs/tate-galois_cohomology.pdf uses this symbol for the Shafarevich group

Comment: I should have guessed it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Cyrillic Sh, probably for Shafarevich